# Alternative for keras.layers.StringLookup for tensorflow-gpu = 2.0.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Need an alternative for `keras.layers.StringLookup` as it is not present in `tensorflow-gpu=2.0.0`. I can't upgrade my `tensorflow-gpu` library as my GPU doesn't support it.

[image: using keras.layers.StringLookup it gives me this error:]

Comment: Hi!Could you confirm your device configuration details and issue happening with upgrading Tensorflow version ?